# Do photons with a frequency of less than 1 Hz exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency

A photon with a frequency of less than 1 Hz would have an energy below
$$
E = h\nu < 6.626×10^{−34} \;\rm J 
$$
which would be less than the value of Planck's constant. Do photons with such a low energy exist and how could they be detected? Or does Planck's constant give a limit on the amount of energy that is necessary to create a single photon?

Comment: Strongly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20713/17609

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Planck constant is $h=6.626\times 10^{-34}\;\rm J\,s$ (joule seconds), you cannot compare it to an energy which is measured in Joules - this is the flaw in your argument. To answer the question: Such low energy photons can exist in principle, however the question is how to actually generate them. I'd propose to take a possibly low energy photon and redshift it (check Doppler effect). It will, however, be in very red radio range and therefore hard to detect.

Comment: The OP has multiplied $h$ by the frequency in Hz (which in this case is 1Hz) so will definitely get an energy in $J$, so they can be compared

Comment: Who is "they"? As far as I can see, he compared $h$ with the energy $E$ of a $1Hz$ photon. $E$ is an energy, $h$ is not.

Comment: the energy of a 1Hz photon *is* $6.6\times 10^{-34}J$, numerically equal to the value for $h$ in SI units, and this is a tiny energy

Comment: Sorry, the second half of the answer is silly. There is absolutely no problem in producing photons of less-than-one-hertz frequency. Just oscillate with a charge at a frequency less than one hertz and be sure that lots of electromagnetic waves are produced. The waves are composed of many photons - at such low frequencies, we actually produce a huge number of photons. What is hard is to "count" them or experimentally prove that the number is integer - it is not hard to produce them.

Comment: danimal: What does it mean physically if two quantities are equal numerically which are of different type? SI units are entirely arbitrary, therefore it is only possible to compare quantities in the same units (or dimensionless quantities without any units at all).

Comment: Luboš Motl: Right, I had characteristic radiation in mind and didn't think about bremsstrahlung.

Comment: @Photon, it doesn't physically mean anything to compare something like, say 3.2m and 3.2kg (obviously), or 6.6Js and 6.6J, but the OP has calculated the energy (in J) of a 1Hz photon, and found that it's energy is tiny...

Comment: The energy is obviously tiny compared to, say, energies within the optical spectrum. But it doesn't make any sense to compare this energy to the Planck constant (exactly for the reason you described) - and that's what the OP did.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency $\nu$ is in seconds$^{-1}$, which is purely human-based unit having a relation to rotation of the Earth. Thus no reason why 1 Hz was a limit. Planck $h$ value is also not massless unit and it's value has relation to SI system.

Existence: while I don't see a principal reason for non-existence of such a photon, neither I see a physical process, that would generate such a radiation. You would need some anthena of length $\sim 10 ^8$ meters and some process that would correlate a charge across such a distance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a long antenna to radiate at 1 Hz.  You need a long antenna to radiate *efficiently* at 1 Hz.  The efficiency is proportional to the cube of the length of the antenna in wavelengths (look up {electrically} 'small antennas').  A big 1 Hz current in a short wire will radiate very little power, but 1 photon a second would be 6.6e-34 Watts, so the numbers may be in favour of radiation.  1 Hz ==> 3e8 m wavelength, so 1 m long wire antenna may have efficiency of order 3e-26, which looks like lots of photons per watt into the antenna (most of the watt goes into resistive, dielectric and magnetic losses in the matching circuit or the generator).

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer for why such photons "exist" is that whether a given photon qualifies depends on your rest frame. Take your favourite high-frequency photon in the universe, say of frequency $n$ Hertz in your rest frame. With a Lorentz boost $-\beta$, I multiply this by $\gamma (1-\beta)=\cosh\phi-\sinh\phi=e^(-\phi)$ with $\phi$ the rapidity $\phi=\mathrm{artanh}\beta$. Setting $\phi>\ln n$ (equivalently, $\beta>\frac{1-n^{-2}}{1+n^{-2}}$) does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Essentially any frequency > 0 is theoretically possible. You may have confused this with the concept that it’s not possible for an electromagnetic wave with a given frequency f to have an energy less than E = h.f without eliminating the entire wave.

Answer (score 0):

Does this mean that very low frequency waves need a minimum intensity to exist so there is at least one photon of minimum energy? Baring that does the wave getting long enough mean the effect is to big for quantum mechanics it apply to it? Neither idea seems to make a lot of sense but accepted quantum theory is about as bad for giving people trying to reason logically headaches. The universe seems to have minimum values for distance and time so does the minimum value of time limit frequency upper limit and the minimum length limit minimum wavelength? It would make some sense if there is a minimum photon energy to propagate a wave but does something strange happen if such a photon is redshifted? It would be a surprise if such photons became another form of energy entirely but who knows. If someone who knows this better could address this I would be grateful.

Answer (score -1):

Photons are a convenient way of explaining some effects, however wave theory is more comprehensive (and complicated).

However all effects should ultimately be understandable from both perspectives.

I think Afarro explain it best, and to answer your question that yes as frequency drops energy drops until no waves or photons can be supported  as they are below minimum energy quanta.

Its interesting to note that in free space this minimum energy quanta is physically very large.  I dont know how to calculate it without some further thought.

This also implies very long times which could